# C# and Excel - Group Rows and move the Plus/Minus Icon

Tags: c#, excel

I'm grouping some rows in my Excel sheet to some specific groups via C#. The Plus/Minus buttons that appear on the left (to fold and unfold these groups) are set a bit to low. [image: Excel Sheet Picture]

It appears like the first plus-button is attached to the second item. In this case i only have 3 groups, but soon there are going to be like 400 of them. When someone else is working with this sheet he/she may not know which buttons belongs to which groups/items.

What can i do to make it more clear?

Here is the code i use to group these rows:

```
static Excel.Range myRange;
...
String rangeStr = (startRow+1) + ":" + endRow;
myRange = worksheet.Rows[rangeStr] as Excel.Range;
myRange.Group();
```

Comment: I believe you should have a summary row for each group, and it should be below the detail, and that is why the outline symbols (+/-) is showing just below the grouped items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
worksheet.Outline.SummaryRow = XlSummaryRow.xlSummaryAbove;
```

This will [move the group plus sign](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2684-excel-group-plus-sign-top.html) to the top of the group instead of the bottom.

Comment: Awesome! Just as i wanted it to be ;)

Comment: @OfficerBacon, `XlSummaryRow.xlSummaryBelow` is the default value means *The summary row will be positioned below the detail rows in the outline.* If you want to move the outline symbols to the top of the group, you should use `XlSummaryRow.xlSummaryAbove`?